# Getting a 'Warning: `NaN` is an invalid value for the `background` css style property.' error

Tags: reactjs, react-animations

react-move/Animate error:
 "Warning: `NaN` is an invalid value for the `background` css style property."

Original code was this:

```
           enter={{
                background: [stripe.background],
            }}
```

SOLUTION:

I changed the value of the background property to a string literal and that fixed the issue.

```
           enter={{
                 background: `${stripe.background}`,
            }}
```

Comment: What is the problem you're facing?

Comment: It wasn’t recognizing the variable as a value because it was in brackets and needed to be changed to a string literal put into braces.

Comment: So it's fixed now?

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb yes

Comment: good job @ReidMcCulloch

Comment: you should probably post that answer in the section below and earn yourself some points :)